# Problem with regex capture group of alternative strings when using Notepad 2

Tags: regex, pipe, notepad2

I have a regex search of the following form which works just fine in decent text editors (such as VS Code), but not in Notepad2 (which is all my client can use):

```
http(s)?://www\.(somedomain\.com|otherdomain\.co\.uk|andanotherdomain\.net)
```

I broke it down and got the first capture group working with [square brackets]:

`http[s]?` works just fine -- no idea why!

…and despite retaining regular brackets for the second group, this works:

```
http[s]?://www\.(somedomain\.com)
```

…but as soon as pipe characters are introduced for alternative strings Notepad2 falls over.

Can anyone help, and maybe explain why Notepad 2 needs something different?

---

Note I'm not too worried about the replace at this point. It's the search pattern that is throwing an error in Notepad2.

Comment: The syntax `http(s)?` makes no sense because the parentheses are used to mark a group of chars for later use. Including a fixed string like `(s)` is useless. `http[s]?` works but doesn't make sense because with `[s]` any character in the set `s`. It will always be `s`. The right use would be `https?` knowing that the `?` is applying only to the previous char, `s` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Notepad2 regex search is based on POSIX BRE that [does not support alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), with some modifications. Amongst the other major shortcomings is the lack of matching across line breaks support.

All supported Notepad2 regex constructs can be checked at the [Notepad2 4.2.25 documentation](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/doc/Notepad2.txt):

```
Regular Expression Syntax

  Note: the Scintilla source code editing component supports only a
  basic subset of regular expression syntax, and searches are limited
  to single lines.

  .      Matches any character.

  (...)  This marks a region for tagging a match.

  \n     Where n is 1 through 9 refers to the first through ninth
         tagged region when replacing. For example, if the search
         string was Fred([1-9])XXX and the replace string was Sam\1YYY,
         when applied to Fred2XXX this would generate Sam2YYY.

  \<     This matches the start of a word.

  \>     This matches the end of a word.

  \x     This allows you to use a character x that would otherwise
         have a special meaning. For example, \[ would be interpreted
         as [ and not as the start of a character set.

  [...]  This indicates a set of characters, for example, [abc] means
         any of the characters a, b or c. You can also use ranges, for
         example [a-z] for any lower case character.

  [^...] The complement of the characters in the set. For example,
         [^A-Za-z] means any character except an alphabetic character.

  ^      This matches the start of a line (unless used inside a set,
         see above).

  $      This matches the end of a line.

  ?      This matches 0 or 1 times. For example, a?b matches ab and b.

  *      This matches 0 or more times. For example, Sa*m matches Sm,
         Sam, Saam, Saaam and so on.

  +      This matches 1 or more times. For example, Sa+m matches Sam,
         Saam, Saaam and so on.

  *?     Causes * and + to behave non-greedy. For example, <.+> matches
  +?     all HTML tags on a line, whereas <.+?> matches only one tag.

  \d     Any decimal digit.
  \D     Any character that is not a decimal digit.

  \s     Any whitespace character.
  \S     Any character that is not a whitespace character.

  \w     Any "word" character.
  \W     Any "non-word" character.

  \xHH   Character with hex code HH.

  -----> Examples (don't use quotes)
         - Quote lines: find "^" replace with "> "
         - Unquote lines: find "^> " replace with ""
         - Remove line numbers: find "^[0-9]+" replace with ""
         - Convert tabs to double spaces: find "\t" replace with "  "
         - Remove NULL bytes: find "\x00" replace with ""
```